# Looking for Compatabile external usb video adapter for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, video, external-monitor

I have a gateway sx that has two video output ports 1 DVI and one VGA. The DVI port went bad and I want to add an external usb vga video card that will work with ubuntu 12.04 64 bit so I can use 2 monitors again.  Does anyone have any recommendations or know of a product that will work with ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Thanks